# SQL transaction rolls back automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, locking

I am using stored procedure and the DML statements are happening in transaction. In the transaction we are updating multiple columns like below:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [YR] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [YR] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [TYBEG] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [TYBEG] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [TYEND] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [TYEND] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [PSEQ] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [PSEQ] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [CTI] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [CTI] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [GTI] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [GTI] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [PTI] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [PTI] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [TIPR] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [TIPR] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [RAR] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [RAR] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [TMOD_E] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [TMOD_E] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [ATI] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [ATI] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [PERC] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [PERC] = ' ';

UPDATE TBLMarket 
SET [PPCT] = NULL 
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId 
  AND [PPCT] = ' ';
.
.
.
.
.
-----120 update statements
.
.

COMMIT TRAN
```

But when I run multiple transactions in parallel(we tried with 50 transaction), we are getting this error.

> Transaction (Process ID 102) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Note: each transaction will have different `@pi_ImportTrnId`, which means transaction running in parallel will never try to update the same set of row.

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" - don't do that!

Comment: @MitchWheat Same issue even after removing the Isolation level.

Comment: This query can be easily rewritten into single statement. You have made a strange choice of isolation level and my guess is that there is no index on `ImportTrnId`.

Comment: Are there any triggers by the way?

Comment: @user1098708: removing "uncommitted" wasn't to fix your immediate problem: it was to stop bad data being read from other processes

Comment: As others have said - a single `UPDATE` would be much preferred here. And give it the *set* of `ImportTrnId`s to work with rather than running the same query multiple times with different values of `@pi_ImportTrnId`

Comment: is there an index on ImportTrnId ? are your stats up to date?

Comment: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Modifying the script to have only one update statement using the CASE, have resolved the issue. Thanks for the responses.
Still one question is spinning in my head, why was I getting deadlock issue with the previous approach. As far as I know while updating SQL applies lock only on the row it's trying to update.

Comment: @IvanStarostin there were no triggers.
_MitchWheat Got you.
_IvanStarostin There are no indexes. Apart from the Primary key which was a different column.

Answer (score 2):

`There are no indexes` - that is the issue. Place an index on `ImportTrnId` column,
rewrite your query in a single-statement manner, remove `READ UNCOMMITTER` and it will run just fine.

```
UPDATE t SET
  [YR] = ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(t.[YR]), ''), t.[YR]),
  [TYBEG] = ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(t.[TYBEG]), ''), t.[TYBEG]),
  ...
FROM TBLMarket t
WHERE ImportTrnId = @pi_ImportTrnId
```